# Como alterar as releases de dev-master para stable composer

Tags: laravel, socket, composer

Estou criando um pacote para sockets em PHP para Laravel, mas eu não consigo apenas usar o composer require pois o pacote esta em dev-master e claro eu não quero mudar todo minha aplicação principal para aceitar pacotes em dev-master. Alguem poderia me ajudar a fazer uma release stable detectável pelo packagist?

Comment: Qual é o pacote? isso é feito no repositório Git, ele lhe da a opção de criar um realease e o packgist carrega ( se tiver configurado se não tem que força pelo botão.)

Comment: marcuscampos/laravel-socket eu ja configurei tudo, mas ele não instala se eu não colocar na versão como dev-master.

Comment: dá uma olhada porque o arquivo `composer.json` está faltando configurar o `autoload`

Comment: Só reafirmando, ele instala a versão `1.1.2`, mas, como seu `composer.json` falta a configuração do `autoload psr-4` ele não carrega as suas classes para serem utilizadas arrume isso e pronto vai funcionar. eu removeria as outras versões por causa desse problema.

Comment: Funcionou!!! Muito obrigado!